# Java method().method() calling

Tags: java, arraylist, compiler-errors

How, if it's possible, can you call a `method` from another method's `return`?

For example...

```
class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point t1 = new Point(0,0);
        Point t2 = new Point(0,1);
        ArrayList pointContainer = new ArrayList();
        pointContainer.add(0,t1);
        pointContainer.add(0,t2);    // We now have an ArrayList containing t1 & t2
        System.out.println(pointContainer.get(1).getLocation()); // The problem area
    }
}
```

In the poorly written example, I'm trying to invoke the `getLocation()` method (part of `java.swing.awt`) on index item 1 of `pointContainer`.

When trying to compile the program, I get the following error...

```
HW.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println(test.get(1).getLocation());
                                  ^
  symbol:   method getLocation()
  location: class Object
```

Could someone please help me with this problem.

Comment: "*Here's a silly question*". May not be but the *question title* is obvious.

Comment: I'd hoped it was clear enough. I wasn't sure which terms to google or label as, alas!

Comment: @KayDee I think the point Lion was making was that your question title answers your question. `method().method()` should work.

Comment: @Lattyware: "Should" is the operative word; the issue, as it turned out, was in messing up the ArrayList set-up (see Makoto's answer below)...which, in turn, screwed up the method().method() calling. I'm just starting Java, so I'm not always entirely sure which "tricks" work with Java, and which ones are, for example, strictly for python.

Comment: Well, it did work as intended, it was just that in your particular case, the object didn't have that method (due to the fact that to Java, it was a generic Object, nothing more).

Comment: For future posts: When any of the posts are an answer, you should mark it as an answer. If you find the answer by yourself, please don't edit your post saying that you found it, instead make a post to answer your own question and mark it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza; just rectified that error, sort of went on autopilot and clicked the "was this post useful" button instead. Sorry about that, and thanks for the notice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, type your ArrayList so that Java can know what objects are coming out of it.

```
List<Point> pointContainer = new ArrayList<Point>();
```

Then, any objects you retrieve from that ArrayList will be of type `Point`, so you can perform operations on them.

Comment: Awesome, that works wonderfully. Most of my googling in those regards made it sound like the <Type> addition was restricted to simple variables (int, String, etc)-- good to know that's not quite the case. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your case you need to do an explicit cast to the `Point` and then call the intended method. Otherwise you need to have the arraylist defined in java generics way as mentioned by @Makoto.

Casting way is

`((Point)pointContainer.get(1)).getLocation()`

Comment: I'll be sticking with Makoto's solution this time-- but I'll keep that in mind for future reference, thank you.

Comment: yes you have to stick to generics absolutely. just mentioned this is also a way.